# Подсчет количества строк в *.py файлах во всей директории проекта

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Доброго времени суток,

Для ДЗ понадобилось подсчитать количество строк в *.py файлах в директории проекта
Получился следующий код:

```py
import os
from collections.abc import Iterable


def gen_files_dir(path: str, depth=1) -> Iterable[str]:
    depth -= 1
    with os.scandir(path) as p:
        for entry in p:
            yield entry.path
            if entry.is_dir() and depth > 0:
                yield from gen_files_dir(entry.path, depth)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = 'C:\\Users\\Nikita.Uvaliyev.KPI\\PycharmProjects\\python-ds\\'
    files_list = list(gen_files_dir(directory))
    line_count = 0

    for file_dir in files_list:
        if not os.path.isfile(file_dir):
            continue

        skip_File = True
        files_filtered = [x for x in files_list if x.endswith('.py')]

        if not skip_File:
            try:
                file = open(file_dir, "r")
                local_count = 0
                for line in file.read().split('\n'):
                    if (not line.strip() == '') and (not line.strip().startswith("#")) and (
                            not line.strip().startswith('"')):
                        local_count += 1
                print('{} - {} ст'.format(file_dir, local_count))
                line_count += local_count
                file.close()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                continue

    print("=====================================")
    print("Всего строк  - ", line_count)
```

Код собран из частей найденных в интернете :)
Пробовал "играться" с путями, но резульат всегда один:

> =====================================
>
> Всего строк  -  0
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Так же, PyCharm жалуется на отсутствие некоторых методов в "**init**", но их добавление ни к чему не приводит

Направьте пожалуйста на путь истинный :)

Comment: Подсчет line_count у Вас идёт в "if not skip_File:", а параметр skip_File у вас установлен чуть выше как True. поэтому он никогда не заходит в алгоритм подсчета. Исправьте его на False или уберите проверку вовсе

Comment: `dir -Recurse *.py | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из-за проверки с `skip_File` код подсчета не выполняется

```
        skip_File = True
        files_filtered = [x for x in files_list if x.endswith('.py')]

        if not skip_File:
            ...
```

Да и код перегруженный, есть возможность сократить его в разы. Кроме того, мне показалось, что он неправильно работает

Сделал решение через `pathlib` и рекурсивный `.rglob` (для поиска текущей папки просто использовать `.glob`):

```
from pathlib import Path


directory = Path(r'C:\Users\Nikita.Uvaliyev.KPI\PycharmProjects\python-ds')
line_count = 0

for f in directory.rglob('*.py'):
    if not f.is_file() or not f.exists():
        continue

    local_count = 0
    for line in f.read_text().splitlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line.startswith(('#', '"', "'")):
            continue
        local_count += 1
    
    print(f'{f} - {local_count} ст')
    line_count += local_count

print("=====================================")
print(f"Всего строк - {line_count}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Если честно, то даже не хочется разбираться в вашем коде.

Приведу пример как я бы это решал:

```
import os

strings = 0

files = os.listdir()
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            with open(file) as f:
                ss = f.read().split('\n')
                for s in ss:
                    if s.strip() and not s.startswith('#') and not s.startswith('"') and not s.startswith("'"):
                        strings += 1

print('Всего строк:', strings )
```

Еще - просто уберите `skip_Path`

Comment: У автора код при подсчете строк еще игнорирует пустые строки, строки-комментарии и те, что начинаются на кавычку :)

Comment: @gil9red исправил

Comment: Пустые строки они будут пустыми :) Поэтому, проверка на `' '` не очень. Лучше уберите лишние символы через `strip` :) Кст, вы правильно сделали, что добавили и одинарные кавычки

Comment: @gil9red у меня в условия стоить просто `s`. Это проверяет что она не пустая